# Where is latest build of osm2pgsql for Windows 64-bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, osm2pgsql

I am using some earlier build for Windows 64-bit downloaded form here:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63393258/osm2pgsql_testRelease.zip
from this website:
awcull.com/2015/09/30/postgis-osm2pgsql-windows.html

but it is crashing when I am importing large pbf with whole Europe downloaded from download.geofabrik.de/

I'm tired of this shit... I tried slim and non-slim mode, I tried modifying cache size, nothing worked so far. Our server has 32 GB of RAM.
Where can I download latest osm2pgsql build for Windows 64-bit? Alternatively which compiler do you suggest to make my own build on Windows Server 2012 64-bit. Thanks.

The command I run osm2pgsql last time it crashed was:

```
PS C:\OSM\rendering> osm2pgsql -U postgres -m -d osm -p osm -E 3857 -s -C 25000 -S C:\OSM\osm2pgsql\default.style C:\OSM\Data\europe-latest.osm.pbf
```

It crashed with standard Windows dialog saying "the application stopped blablabla" with details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: osm2pgsql.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    53ea21fd
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18438
  Fault Module Timestamp:   57ae642e
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0000000000030d02
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 33ad
  Additional Information 2: 33ad00700702b0ab4dc632df7667ec82
  Additional Information 3: 2ebb
  Additional Information 4: 2ebbf5b91303f76c5b7f75f6255100fa

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Now I'm trying without "-C" option but I bet it will crash again...

```
PS C:\OSM\rendering> osm2pgsql -U postgres -m -d osm -p osm -E 3857 -s -S C:\OSM\osm2pgsql\default.style C:\OSM\Data\europe-latest.osm.pbf
```

Answer (score 2):

Necromancing.

The latest build (Continuous Integration) can always be found on [AppVeyor](https://appveyor.com/). 
You need to get the current build (or in history a historic build by the git-commit hash).

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql

```
=> Environment arch x64
=> Artifacts tab
=> Donwload osm2pgsql_Release_x64.zip
```

The link might break, so if it does, you need to google "appveyor osm2pgsql", 
it should usually be the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Download from [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118334/download-link-to-osm2pgsql)

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql)

Here is the [Hot-Installer reference.](https://github.com/hotosm/installer/downloads)